# Как вставить текст в текстовый файл на определенной строке или после определенного слова

Tags: html, файлы, ruby

Мне нужно создать метод который будет вставлять переданные ему значения в тело файла `index.html` (сразу после первого `<body>`).

Вот, есть код:

```rb
class New_class
  def status(sourse, hp, sleep)
    @sourse = sourse
    File.open(@sourse, 'a'){ |file| file.puts  hp, sleep }
  end
end

tamgem = New_class.new
tamgem.status("index.html", 20, 20)
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы числа, которые я передаю этому методу, вставлялись в тело *HTML*-документа? Также прошу заметить, что это чистый руби (не рельсы).

Comment: Уточню.  У вас в файле уже есть место для этих чисел?  Например, занятое пробелами?  Или вы хотите их добавить, чтобы после этой операции размер файла увеличился?

Comment: Хотя нет. Место для них можно сделать, это не проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не называйте так классы, принято назваеть классы в [CamelCase](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes)

Для работы с HTML/XML смотрите в сторону [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html) Можете прочитать файл, затем вставить что хотите в body и записать это все в index.html